# conditional rendering order of the elements based on props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I created a search input component and this input has an icon which I need to change the icon's align (on the left side or right side) based on different situations (it's a bootstrap input-group) so all I need to do is change the order of elements inside my div and I need a clean way to do this. I know I can use a ternary operation to conditional render my elements but this would cause to repeat the code. I'm looking for much cleaner way so any suggestions?

```js
const SearchInput = ({onClose, onChangeValue, ...restProps}) => {
    return (
        <div className='input-group'>
            <button className='btn' type='button'> //right now its on left side...
                <i className='bi bi-search'></i>
            </button>
            <Input placeholder='Search here...' onChangeValue={onChangeValue} {...restProps} />
            {onClose && <i className='bi bi-x' onClick={onClose}></i>}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: as I believe, conditional rendering is the one you should use in this kind of case. But why do you say that it's not a clean way of doing things ?

Comment: yes, but I don't know I feel like I'm repeating the code in this way..@KavinduVIndika

Comment: So you can create a separate component for the conditionally rendering part and then use it. Then you can avoid repetitions right? But if it just a button, then I don't think it's essential to create a separate component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal

```
import clsx from 'clsx';
const SearchInput = ({onClose, onChangeValue, conditionProp, ...restProps}) => {
    return (
        <div className={clsx('input-group', conditionProp && 'my-order)}>
            <button className='btn' type='button'> //right now its on left side...
                <i className='bi bi-search'></i>
            </button>
            <Input placeholder='Search here...' onChangeValue={onChangeValue} {...restProps} />
            {onClose && <i className='bi bi-x' onClick={onClose}></i>}
        </div>
    );
};
```

In CSS

```css
.my-order {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

I like `cslsx` for conditional classnames, but of course I can do without it -  `conditionProp ? 'input-group my-order' : 'input-group'`